# Progress Bar on an AJAX request not working with PHP files

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show a progress bar when I fire an ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://www.domain.de/test.html',
xhrFields: {
    onprogress: function(e) {
        if(e.lengthComputable) {
            _this.find('.process-loading').attr('style', 'width:' + (e.loaded / e.total * 100) + '%');
        }
    },
}
});
```

That works pretty well as long as I use `*.html` files or `*.txt` files or images. But when I want to upload a `*.php` file "lengthComputable" is false and "total" is zero.

Why doesn't it work with this kind of files? What can I change or must I somehow allow PHP files?

Answer (score 0):

This is because PHP scripts outputs dynamic content and the content length for the output is a variable, to solve this you need to set the proper Content-Length header in your PHP script, try to put the following code snippet into your PHP file:

```
<?php
  ob_start();

  //** Put your own PHP logic in this place**

   header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
   header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
   ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Hope this helps